# Adding entries to the context menu and organising them in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, regedit, context-menu

So I've got the hang of adding keys to HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\Shell, and I know I can add a string entitled 'Position' and change its value to position the entry I've made, but I can't figure out how to do three things (nor can I find anything guiding me in doing them):

1) How to put a bar on either side of an entry to separate it from other entries

2) How to position them in an exact place in the context menu (eg. above or below a certain other entry)

3) How to make an entry that brings up another list of entries (like the 'View' and 'Sort by' entries that are already there when you right-click in Windows Explorer

I wasn't sure whether this goes in StackOverflow or SuperUser, but I thought maybe it goes here since I'm using Regedit rather than coding it (though I am aware you can right a .reg file and then execute it to install these sorts of things). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry but way to much to type. So instead here is a present.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144171%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

All you need to know about context menu.